# ffill weird behavior , when have the duplicate columns names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as below

---

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,1,1,np.nan],'B':[2,np.nan,2,2]},index=[1,1,2,2])
df.columns=['A','A']
```

---

Now I want to `ffill` the values `groupby` the `index` , first I try

```
df.groupby(level=0).ffill()
```

Which returns the error code

```
> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

It looks like a bug, then I am trying with apply, which returns the expected output.

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.ffill())
     A    A
1  NaN  2.0
1  1.0  2.0
2  1.0  2.0
2  1.0  2.0
```

For your reference when the columns is unique , it works ***just***(Q2) fine, however, create one index columns and columns name is `NaN`

```
df.columns=['C','D']
df.groupby(level=0).ffill()
   NaN    C    D
1    1  NaN  2.0
1    1  1.0  2.0
2    2  1.0  2.0
2    2  1.0  2.0
```

---

> Question :
> 1 Is this a bug ? why apply can still work with this type situation ?
>
> 2 why `groupby` with `index` and `ffill`, it creates the additional columns ?

Comment: what version?  0.22 `df.groupby(level=0).ffill()` works for me.

Comment: @piRSquared I am in pd.__version__: '0.23.4' and pd.__version__: '0.24'

Comment: yeah, my 0.24 fails as well

Comment: That is way buggy.

Comment: @piRSquared also , even without the columns name dup , the ffill create wired columns ..:-(

Comment: I also confirmed that.

Comment: see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25610; could probably add a comment with the `level=0` behavior to make sure that gets tested too when a fix goes in

Comment: @Yuca you are right :-) typo .

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug as I have encountered this very issue before with duplicate names.

Comment: @coldspeed ok , will follow up with the GitHub open issue

Comment: @Wen-Ben This works fine for me, gives expected output just as `apply` does, but i am on a old version... `0.19.2`

Comment: I tried on `repl.it` for `0.24.2` gives error as well

Comment: Have you already opened a bug ticket on the pandas board, so the pandas team can check this? If you like to do this, you can get more info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing.html#bug-reports-and-enhancement-requests

Comment: @jezrael sure will do

Comment: @ScottBoston Still learning ~ :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks bugged. Just wanted to note that according to the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) the `.ffill()` method is a synonym for `.fillna(method='ffill')`. Using the latter generates your expected output for both your examples in pandas version `0.23.4` without any errors or additional columns. Hope that helps.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,1,1,np.nan],'B':[2,np.nan,2,2]},index=[1,1,2,2])

df.columns=['A','A'] #dup column names
df.groupby(level=0).fillna(method='ffill')

Output:
    A   A
1   NaN 2.0
1   1.0 2.0
2   1.0 2.0
2   1.0 2.0
```