# How can I return the first item of a split in a lambda in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, split

so I need to split a data Frame column and get the first item to put in a new column with a lambda fuction. I can't figure out how to do that.

```py
df['Reason'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':'))
```

I'm getting this for now:

```py
df['Reason'].head()

0     [EMS,  BACK PAINS/INJURY]
1    [EMS,  DIABETIC EMERGENCY]
2        [Fire,  GAS-ODOR/LEAK]
3     [EMS,  CARDIAC EMERGENCY]
4             [EMS,  DIZZINESS]
```

and I'd like:

```py
df['Reason'].head()

0     [EMS]
1     [EMS]
2     [Fire]
3     [EMS]
4     [EMS]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['abc xyz', 'foo bar', 'test', np.nan]})
df

      text
0  abc xyz
1  foo bar
2     test
3      NaN
```

Use any `str` method. For example, `str.split`:

```
df['text'].str.split(n=1).str[0]

0     abc
1     foo
2    test
3     NaN
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Or `str.partition`:

```
df['text'].str.partition(' ')[0]

0     abc
1     foo
2    test
3     NaN
Name: text, dtype: object
```

---

The methods above make working with NaNs easy. `apply` will fail here:

```
df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

An `isinstance` check is the fix for this,

```
df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.split(None, 1)[0] if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)

0     abc
1     foo
2    test
3     NaN
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Man , would you like check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616929/ffill-weird-behavior-when-have-the-duplicate-columns-names? I thought it is bug , just do not know why apply work here..

Answer (score 2):

I am using `str.findall` with `regex` here

```
df.text.str.findall(r"^\w+").str[0]
0     abc
1     foo
2    test
3     NaN
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column filled with `lists`, just do straightforwardly

```
df['Readon'].str[0]
```

or

```
df['Readon'].str.get(0)
```

Outputs

```
0     [EMS]
1     [EMS]
2     [Fire]
3     [EMS]
4     [EMS]
```

Comment: @Wen-Ben I guess yes. I just used the `df['Reason'].head()` as reference ;p

Answer (score 0):

Take the first item of the list returned by `split()`:

```
df['Reason'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
```

For extra credit, tell `split()` to only split once so that it won't bother splitting more items only to throw them away.

```
df['Reason'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':', 1)[0])
```

Or use `partition()` instead:

```
df['Reason'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.partition(':')[0])
```

Comment: `df['title'].str.split(n=1).str[0]`

Comment: P.S.: [Avoid the use of `apply` as much as possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)